# What does means by rh- in php packages in CentOS?

Tags: php, yum

Following is the result of `yum search php-pdo`

[image: package]

1st one has no php version.
Next two has php version 5.4 and 5.5 respectively.
And next 3 has php version with `rh` at starting.
What is the significance/meaning of `rh`?

Comment: It is "namespaced" for RedHat. [Source](https://www.redhat.com/archives/sclorg/2015-February/msg00022.html)

Comment: Looks like the last 3 will only work on redhat

Comment: @Forbs Won't work in CentOS?

Comment: @user9719859 Where did you install `php` from in the first place? You can use one of the other repos to fetch the files you need if thats what your actually trying to do? & what version of `php` is it you have?

Comment: @user9719859 CentOS is a flavor of Redhat, (an older one).  The first 3 were made for any linux and the last 3 were specifically RedHat or one of it's flavors.